# Ng-debounce for certain functions in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to trigger certain functions on different timeframes when there is an input change. Currently, I have this:

```
<input type="text" name="title" ng-model="title" placeholder="Search..." ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: {'default': 3000, 'blur': 0} }" ng-change="showData()"><br>

<div class="loadSpinnerPost" ng-if=".....">
   <div class="bounce1"></div>
   <div class="bounce2"></div>
   <div class="bounce3"></div>
</div>
```

So at the moment, I only have implement `showData()`. After 3 seconds, this function searches for new data. In the mean time, I would like to show a loader which I want to trigger directly after an input change which I'll call `showLoader()`. When the `showData()` function is done, It should simply disable the loader with `ng-if`.

`showLoader()` should be triggered right after the `ng-change` and `showData()` after three seconds, but I can't figure out how to do this.

What I've tried so far:

1. Instead of using `ng-debounce`, I tried to use a `setTimeout()` in `showData()`. However this only delays when the data is shown instead of making less requests to the back-end.
2. Comparing the value of the input with the old input. But also the value of the model `title` updates after 3 seconds when using `ng-debounce`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ng-keypress` to show the loader and hide it when data is retrieved.

e.g. https://plnkr.co/edit/F4pSTdYgdxbEnxm8ds5q?p=preview